# TCPMON forces you to break the target endpoint into HOSTNAME and PORT

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, tcpmon

My web service endpoint looks like this:
http://www.host.com:8010/webservices/SOAProvider/plsql/xxcpin_ap_supplier_pkg/

So when I use tcpmon to capture outgoing requests and incoming responses, I specify "www.host.com" as the HOSTNAME and 8010 as PORT. Apparently I have no way of specifying the extension "webservices/SOAProvider/plsql/xxcpin_ap_supplier_pkg/" in TCPMON. This makes me believe that my SOAP messages are going reaching the correct endpoint (which is http://www.host.com:8010/webservices/SOAProvider/plsql/xxcpin_ap_supplier_pkg/).

Is there a way or another tool where I can specify the complete endpoint address and trace the soap request and response?

Highly appreciate your response and help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically about AXIS, but in CXF you can add loggers to the endpoint configuration bus.  Same for core JAX-WS where you can specify a handler chain that might include a logging step.

Command line tools that aren't part of the ws implementation (either client or server) don't know the application or protocol specifics, so they can't filter on that specific endpoint request.

You could take the output from `tcpmon` and post-process it to locate only the endpoint you want by looking for:

```
POST webservices/SOAProvider/plsql/xxcpin_ap_supplier_pkg/ HTTP/1.1
```

or something very similar in the data stream.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Fiddler2 is actually quite helpful and solved the problem I had. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I use [Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/) for capturing http/webservice traffic (and [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) for crafting my own requests manually). You can define capture filters in fiddler2.
Both are excellent tools for testing and debugging web services.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Fiddler2 is actually quite helpful and solved the problem I had. Thanks again!